# How to disable plugins in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins

I have few plugins installed in Visual Studio 2008. Is there a way to disable a few of them without uninstalling the specific plugin? I am looking for something visual i.e I dont want to edit the command line used to start Visual Stuio

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling Add-ins (e.g. “Tools” | “Add-in Manager”) or run “devenv.exe /SafeMode”.This can eliminate the possibility that third party Add-ins or packages are causing problems. (For more detailed VS command line switches information, see: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx )

Comment: I have DevPartner installed but it doesnt showup in the list. Similarly VMvare plugin is installed but it doesnt show up either. How do i disable them?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah...of course there is...Just go to Tools menu and select Add-in Manager, then uncheck the addins you don't want to run. You can also remove the check in Startup column to disable the adding when you start Visual Studio. You can always enable them again from Add-in Manager.